# Call to undefined method Template::append_css()

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I am trying to append_css using the code below. On older projects the below code would normally work. For reference i am using CodeIgniter and template Sparks

```
    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('template');
    $this->template
            ->append_css('/public/css/app.css');
  }
    public function index(){    
        $this->template->build('welcome_message.php');
    }
}
```

I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Template::append_css() in /Users/Afont/quals/codeigniter-test/application/controllers/welcome.php on line 9
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your `autoload.php`, you may want to autoload the spark:

`$autoload['sparks'] = array('template/1.9.0');`

Second, looking through the code, it seems that there is no `append_css` function. In `PyroCMS`, the library appears to have that function, but not the spark by default.

Comment: ah i see thanks. I am used to pyro and assumed it was available.